# Как обработать Router React для правильной переадрисации

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Как сделать так,чтобы при перезагрузке страницы отображалась последняя страница, а не происходил редирект на '/stat'?

```
return (
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/stat" exact>
                    <StatPage />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/feedback" exact>
                    <FeedbackPage />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/detail/:id">
                    <Page />
                </Route>
                <Redirect to = '/stat' />
            </Switch>
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, убрать переадресацию на /stat.

Если вы хотите использовать компонент StatPage как стартовый, достаточно сделать

`<Route path="/" exact>`